# ../private_js 404 code.js (Not Found)

Tags: javascript

lets say my site is http://www.example.com

I have a index.php file that uses a .js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
```

obviously theses files (index.php and code.js) are in my public_html directory

I have created a folder above public_html called private_js

I would have thought that hiding javascript code above the public_html would work like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../private_js/code.js"></script>
```

But the browser console shows the error:

```
GET http://example.com/private_js/code.js 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I get this to work (I ave done this before with node.js on the server but not the client).

Comment: Change `src` to use an *absolute* path to your file instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> obviously theses files (index.php and code.js) are in my public_html directory

That's not obvious, but if they are it probably means that `public_html` is the root directory from where your web server (apache, node?) goes looking for resources to serve. That means, when you request `http://www.example.com/index.php` it serves the file `…/public_html/index.php` from your file system.

It will never serve resources outside of that directory, to prevent [directory traversal attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack).

So when you now created `private_js` outside of `public_html`, is not accessible from the internet but only in your local filesystem. Notice that the relative path `../private_js/code.js` on `http://www.example.com/index.php` does resolve to `http://www.example.com/private_js/code.js`, which is done on the client side - that's the url the browser requests. When the server gets it, it will look for a file at `…/public_html/private_js/code.js` where it obviously does not exist.

**Solution**: Configure your server to serve file from `private_js`, or move them into the `public_html` folder.